# Android Studio Database Column Must be > 0 error

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

I'm working on an assignment for a college course. I'm really new to coding so I apologize if this is an obvious fix.
The assignment is:

Create an activity app with two forms.  The main form should have a list view, an add button, an edit button, a view button, and a delete button.  On the click of any button you should navigate the user to the second form that will be populated properly for the button action using data passed using an intent object.  Your second form should be a layout to input a name and address.  The form needs to contain First Name, Last Name, Street Address, Town, State, and Zip code.  All your entry fields should be correctly labeled / Hinted so the user will know what to enter. In addition to the fields you will need an “OK”, "Cancel", and a “Clear” button. If the user clicks the “Clear” button you need to clear all the entries.  If the user clicks the “OK” or “Cancel” buttons, you should return the button selection and form data to the main form using an intent object.  The main activity should process the response and add, update, or delete the record.  All records should be added, updated, or delete within a SQLite database that is automatically created by your application.   Your program should generate an alert message that confirms the action completed.

I'm getting an error in the cursorToAddressAttributeGroup method saying that the value cursor.getColumnIndexshould be greater than 0. How do I set it to be greater than 0?
This is the class that is having the issue:

```
   package com.example.program5;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
     import android.content.Context;
      import android.database.Cursor;
     import android.database.SQLException;
       import android.database.sqlite.*;
       import com.example.program5.AddressCollection.AddressCollectionDB;

public class AddressDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{ 
public static final String TABLE_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_FIRSTNAME = "firstName";
public static final String COLUMN_LASTNAME ="lastName";
public static final String COLUMN_STREET_ADDRESS = "streetAddress";
public static final String COLUMN_TOWN = "town";
public static final  String COLUMN_STATE = "state";
public static final String COLUMN_ZIP ="zip";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "address.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database creation SQL statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "create table "
        + TABLE_ADDRESS  + "("
        + COLUMN_ID      + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        +COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " text not null, "
        +COLUMN_LASTNAME + "text not null, "
        +COLUMN_STREET_ADDRESS + "text not null, "
        +COLUMN_TOWN + "text not null, "
        +COLUMN_STATE + "text not null, "
        +COLUMN_ZIP + "text not null);";


public AddressDatabaseHelper(Context context)
 {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }

//onCreate method creates table
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
{
    //directly executes SQl statement create table
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
}

//onUpgrade method upgrades the table
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    //drops table if it exists
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ADDRESS);

    //calls onCreate method and passes db as an argument
    onCreate(db);

}
}

class AddressDataSource
{    
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private final AddressDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allColumns = { AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID,
        AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_LASTNAME,
        AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_STREET_ADDRESS, AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TOWN,
        AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_STATE, AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ZIP };


//AddressDataSource passes c as argument
public AddressDataSource(Context c)
{
    super();
    // dbHelper equals AddressDatabaseHelper passing c as parameter
    dbHelper = new AddressDatabaseHelper(c);
}


//open method
public void open() throws SQLException {
    //sets database equal to dbHelper.getWritableDatabase
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

//close method
public void close()
{
    //closes dbHelper
    dbHelper.close();
}

//createAddress method passes address as argument
public long createAddress(AddressAttributeGroup address)
{
    //creates new ContentValues object called values
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //puts values of firstname and lastname into COLUMN_NAME
    values.put(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID,address.id);
    values.put(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, address.firstName );
    values.put(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_LASTNAME, address.lastName );
    values.put(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_STREET_ADDRESS, address.streetAddress);
    values.put(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TOWN,
            address.town);
    values.put(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_STATE,address.state);
    values.put(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ZIP,address.zip);
    /* returns insertId */
    long insertId = database.insert(AddressDatabaseHelper.TABLE_ADDRESS,
            null,
            values);
    return insertId;
   // return database.insert(AddressDatabaseHelper.TABLE_ADDRESS,null,values);
}

//deleteAddress method passes address as argument
public void deleteAddress(AddressAttributeGroup address)
{ //sets id equal to address.id
    long id = address.id;

    //deletes the entry stored at address.id in the TABLE_ADDRESS table
    database.delete(AddressDatabaseHelper.TABLE_ADDRESS,
            AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
}

//getAllAddresses method
public AddressCollectionDB getAllAddresses() throws Exception
{ AddressCollectionDB addresses = new AddressCollectionDB();


    Cursor cursor = database.query(AddressDatabaseHelper.TABLE_ADDRESS,
            allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        //adds address to addresses
        addresses.addAddress(cursorToAddressAttributeGroup(cursor));
        //and moves cursor to next entry
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    //closes the cursor
    cursor.close();
    //returns addresses
    return addresses;
}

private AddressAttributeGroup cursorToAddressAttributeGroup(Cursor cursor)
{
            //error must be greater than 0. Figure out what is causing the error?
            (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID)),

                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME)),

                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_LASTNAME)),

                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_STREET_ADDRESS)),

                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TOWN)),

                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_STATE)),

                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ZIP)));
}

}
```

Here are theother classes in the program for context:

AddressAttributeGroup Class:

```
 package com.example.program5;

public class AddressAttributeGroup {
//declare Strings for name and address and a long for the id number
public long id;
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public String streetAddress;
public String town;
public String state;
public String zip;


//constructor
public AddressAttributeGroup(long id, String firstName, String lastName, String streetAddress, 
String town, String state, String zip) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    this.town = town;
    this.state = state;
    this.zip = zip;


  }
```

AddressCollection Class:

```
package com.example.program5;

import android.content.Context;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class AddressCollection {
ArrayList<AddressAttributeGroup> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
final int MAXIMUM_ADDRESS_COUNT = 10;

//boolean that checks if amount of records in arrayList  equal to or greater than limit
public boolean isAddressLimitReached()
{
    return (addressList.size() >= MAXIMUM_ADDRESS_COUNT);

}


public int addAddress(AddressAttributeGroup address) throws Exception {
    //if arrayList is full
    if (isAddressLimitReached())
    {
        throw (new Exception("Maximum Address Reached."));
    }
    //adds new address to the arraylist addressList
    addressList.add(address);

    //returns the index of address
    return addressList.indexOf(address);
}

public void setAddress(int addressIndex, AddressAttributeGroup address) {
    addressList.set(addressIndex, address);
}

public void removeAddress(int addressIndex) {
    //removes address at the index addressIndex
    addressList.remove(addressIndex);
}
//


public AddressAttributeGroup getAddress(int addressIndex) {
    return addressList.get(addressIndex);
}


static class AddressCollectionDB extends AddressCollection
{static public  AddressDataSource addressData;
    public static AddressCollectionDB AddressCollectionFactory(Context context)
    {
        AddressCollectionDB resultCode = new AddressCollectionDB();
        addressData = new AddressDataSource(context);
        try {
            addressData.open();
            resultCode = addressData.getAllAddresses();
            addressData.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultCode;
    }
    public int addAddress (AddressAttributeGroup address) throws Exception
    {
        if (isAddressLimitReached())

            throw (new Exception("Maximum Address Reached."));

        addressData.open();
        address.id = addressData.createAddress(address);
        addressData.close();
        return super.addAddress(address);
    }

    public void setAddress ( int addressIndex, AddressAttributeGroup address)
    {
        addressData.open();
        addressData.deleteAddress(getAddress(addressIndex));
        address.id = addressData.createAddress(address);
        addressData.close();

        super.setAddress(addressIndex, address);
    }


    public void removeAddress ( int addressIndex)
    {
        addressData.open();
        addressData.deleteAddress(getAddress(addressIndex));
        addressData.close();
        super.removeAddress(addressIndex);

    }
 }



}
```

AddressConsole class:

```
package com.example.program5;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.program5.StrongIntent.TypeOfAction;
import com.example.program5.AddressCollection.AddressCollectionDB;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class AddressConsole extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener  {

Button cmdAdd;
Button cmdDelete;
Button cmdView;
Button cmdEdit;
TextView textAddressMessage;
EditText editRecordNumber;
ListView listOfAddresses;
final int ADDRESS_ENTRY = 1001;
AddressCollectionDB addresses;
//AddressCollection addresses = new AddressCollection();
AddressArrayAdapter addressAdapter;
int recordNumber = +1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.address_console);
    textAddressMessage = findViewById(R.id.textAddressMessage);
    editRecordNumber = findViewById(R.id.editRecordNumber);
    cmdAdd = findViewById(R.id.cmdAdd);
    cmdAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    cmdEdit = findViewById(R.id.cmdEdit);
    cmdEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
    cmdDelete = findViewById(R.id.cmdDelete);
    cmdDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    cmdView = findViewById(R.id.cmdView);
    cmdView.setOnClickListener(this);
    listOfAddresses = findViewById(R.id.listOfAddresses);
    listOfAddresses.setOnItemClickListener (this);
    listOfAddresses.setOnItemSelectedListener( this);
    addresses = AddressCollectionDB.AddressCollectionFactory(this);
    addressAdapter = new AddressArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, addresses);
    listOfAddresses.setAdapter(addressAdapter);



}
void displayError(Exception message) {
    Toast.makeText(this,message.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

void displayError(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Maximum Number Of Addresses Reached!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

void displayInfo(String message)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//hmm why is this never used?
void displayAddressMessage(AddressAttributeGroup address)
{//issue
    textAddressMessage.setText("Address:" + address.firstName + " " + address.lastName + " " + 
  address.streetAddress + " "
        + address.town + "" + address.state + " " + address.zip);
}

void clearAddressMessage()

{
    textAddressMessage.setText("");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    StrongIntent intent;
    //if user clicks add button
    if(cmdAdd.getId() == view.getId())
    {
        //if address limit has not been reached
        if(!addresses.isAddressLimitReached())
        {
            //intent equals new Strong Intent
            intent = new StrongIntent();
            //intent action is equal to ADD
            intent.action = TypeOfAction.ADD;

            startActivityForResult(intent.getIntent(this, AddressEntry.class),ADDRESS_ENTRY);
        }
        //else
        else
            //calls display error message
            displayError();
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            {
                AddressAttributeGroup address = addresses.getAddress(recordNumber);
                //if user clicks edit
                if(cmdEdit.getId() == view.getId())
                {
                    //intent equals new StrongIntent passing address, typeOfAction and record number as arguments
                    intent = new StrongIntent(address,TypeOfAction.EDIT,recordNumber);

                    startActivityForResult(intent.getIntent(this,AddressEntry.class),ADDRESS_ENTRY);

                }
                //if user clicks delete button
                if(cmdDelete.getId()==view.getId())
                {
                    //intent equals StrongIntent passing address DELETE and record number as arguments
                    intent = new StrongIntent(address, TypeOfAction.DELETE,recordNumber);
                    startActivityForResult(intent.getIntent(this,AddressEntry.class),ADDRESS_ENTRY);
                }
                //if user clicks view
                if(cmdView.getId() == view.getId())
                {
                    //calls displayAddressMessage and passes address as an argument
                    displayAddressMessage(address);
                }
            }
            //catch block
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            displayError(ex);
        }
    }
}

@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

{
    StrongIntent addressIntent = new StrongIntent(data);
    if (requestCode == ADDRESS_ENTRY) {
        try {
            //switch statement passes resultCode as argument

            switch (resultCode) {
                case RESULT_OK:
                    AddressAttributeGroup address = new AddressAttributeGroup(addressIntent.addressIndex,addressIntent.firstName, addressIntent.lastName,
                            addressIntent.streetAddress, addressIntent.town, addressIntent.state, addressIntent.zip);
                    switch (addressIntent.action) {
                        case ADD:
                            addresses.addAddress(address);
                            displayAddressMessage(address);
                            displayInfo("Added + Address:" + address.firstName + " " + address.lastName + " " + address.streetAddress + " "
                                    + address.town + "" + address.state + " " + address.zip);
                            break;

                        case DELETE:
                            addresses.removeAddress(addressIntent.addressIndex);
                            displayInfo("Address Deleted");
                            clearAddressMessage();
                            editRecordNumber.setText("");
                            recordNumber =-1;
                            break;

                        case EDIT:
                            addresses.setAddress(addressIntent.addressIndex,address);

                            displayAddressMessage(address);
                            displayInfo("Address Updated");

                            break;
                    }

                    addressAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    break;

                case RESULT_CANCELED:
                    displayInfo("Cancelled");
                    break;
            }
        }
        //catch block
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            displayError(ex);
        }

    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    onItemSelected(parent, view, position,id);

    AddressAttributeGroup address = addresses.getAddress(recordNumber);
    displayAddressMessage(address);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    recordNumber = position;
    editRecordNumber.setText(String.valueOf(recordNumber));

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}


class AddressArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AddressAttributeGroup> {
    private final Context context;

    private final AddressCollection addresses;

    public AddressArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, AddressCollection addresses) {
        super(context, resource, addresses.addressList);

        this.context = context;

        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        AddressAttributeGroup address = addresses.getAddress(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        TextView firstNameTextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.editFirstName);
        TextView lastNameTextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.editLastName);
        TextView addressTextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.editStreetAddress);
        TextView townTextView;
        townTextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.editTown);
        TextView stateTextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.editState);
        TextView zipTextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.editZip);

        firstNameTextView.setText(address.firstName);
        lastNameTextView.setText(address.lastName);
        addressTextView.setText(address.streetAddress);
        townTextView.setText(address.town);
        stateTextView.setText(address.state);
        zipTextView.setText(address.zip);

        return rowView;
    }
}

}
```

Strong Intent Class:

```
 package com.example.program5;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class StrongIntent
{
public String firstName;

public String lastName;

public String streetAddress;

public String town;

public String state;

public String zip;

public enum TypeOfAction
{
    ADD,
    EDIT,
    DELETE
}
TypeOfAction action;
int addressIndex = +1;
Intent intent;

public StrongIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    //try/catch block for retrieving key value pairs for intent bundle
    try
    {
        firstName = bundle.getString("firstName");

        lastName = bundle.getString("lastName");

        streetAddress = bundle.getString("streetAddress");

        town = bundle.getString("town");

        state = bundle.getString("state");

        zip = bundle.getString("zip");

        //retrieves the action type chosen
        action = TypeOfAction.values()[bundle.getInt("action",0)];

        //gets address index
        addressIndex = bundle.getInt("addressIndex");
    }
    //catch block
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}



//constructor
public StrongIntent()
{ firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    streetAddress = "";
    town = "";
    state= "";
    zip = "";


}
//constructor which passes addressAttributes, action and addressIndex as arguments
public StrongIntent(AddressAttributeGroup addressAttributes, TypeOfAction action, int addressIndex)
{
    firstName = addressAttributes.firstName;
    lastName = addressAttributes.lastName;
    streetAddress = addressAttributes.streetAddress;
    town = addressAttributes.town;
    state= addressAttributes.state;
    zip = addressAttributes.zip;

    this.action = action;
    this.addressIndex = addressIndex;
}

//sets intent equal to null
public void clearIntent()
{
    intent = null;

}
//adds data to intent bundle
void putExtras()
{
    intent.putExtra("firstName",firstName);
    intent.putExtra("lastName",lastName);
    intent.putExtra("streetAddress",streetAddress);
    intent.putExtra("town",town);
    intent.putExtra("state",state);
    intent.putExtra("zip",zip);
    intent.putExtra("action",action.ordinal());
    intent.putExtra("addressIndex",addressIndex);
}

public Intent getIntent()
{   //if intent is equal to null
    if (intent == null)

    //sets intent equal to new Intent
    { intent = new Intent();

        //calls putExtras method
        putExtras();
    }
    //returns intent
    return intent;
}

public Intent getIntent(Activity addressEntry,
                        Class<AddressEntry> class1)
{
    //if intent is equal to null
    if (intent == null)

    {
        intent = new Intent(addressEntry,class1);

        //calls putExtras method
        putExtras();
    }
    //returns intent
    return intent;
}

}
```

AddressEntry Class:

```
package com.example.program5;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddressEntry extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button cmdSave;
Button cmdClear;
Button cmdCancel;
EditText editFirstName;
EditText editLastName;
EditText editStreetAddress;
EditText editTown;
EditText editState;
EditText editZip;
int result;
StrongIntent stIntent;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.address_entry);
    editFirstName = findViewById(R.id.editFirstName);
    editLastName = findViewById(R.id.editLastName);
    editStreetAddress = findViewById(R.id.editStreetAddress) ;
    editTown = findViewById(R.id.editTown);
    editState = findViewById(R.id.editState);
    editZip = findViewById(R.id.editZip);

    cmdSave = findViewById(R.id.cmdSave);
    cmdSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    cmdClear = findViewById(R.id.cmdClear);
    cmdClear.setOnClickListener(this);
    cmdCancel =  findViewById(R.id.cmdCancel);
    cmdCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    stIntent = new StrongIntent(getIntent());
    editFirstName.setText(stIntent.firstName);
    editLastName.setText(stIntent.lastName);
    editStreetAddress.setText(stIntent.streetAddress);
    editTown.setText(stIntent.town);
    editState.setText(stIntent.state);
    editZip.setText(stIntent.zip);
    //if the type of action is equal to DELETE
    if (stIntent.action ==StrongIntent.TypeOfAction.DELETE)
        //if user clicks Save sets text to Delete
        cmdSave.setText(R.string.deleteString);
    //enables action when delete is not selected
    editFirstName.setEnabled(stIntent.action!=StrongIntent.TypeOfAction.DELETE);
    editLastName.setEnabled(stIntent.action!=StrongIntent.TypeOfAction.DELETE);
    editStreetAddress.setEnabled(stIntent.action != StrongIntent.TypeOfAction.DELETE);
    editTown.setEnabled(stIntent.action != StrongIntent.TypeOfAction.DELETE);
    editState.setEnabled(stIntent.action != StrongIntent.TypeOfAction.DELETE);
    editZip.setEnabled(stIntent.action != StrongIntent.TypeOfAction.DELETE);
    cmdClear.setEnabled(stIntent.action!=StrongIntent.TypeOfAction.DELETE);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    //if Save is clicked
    if(cmdSave.getId() == view.getId())
    {
        //result equals RESULT_OK
        result = RESULT_OK;

        //calls the finish method
        finish();

    }
    //if Clear is clicked
    if(cmdClear.getId() == view.getId())
    //clears all values entered
    { editFirstName.setText("");
        editLastName.setText("");
        editStreetAddress.setText("");
        editTown.setText("");
        editState.setText("");
        editZip.setText("");

    }//if Cancel is clicked
    if(cmdCancel.getId() == view.getId())
    { //result is equal to RESULT_CANCELED
        result = RESULT_CANCELED;
        //calls finish method
        finish();

    }
}
@Override
public void finish()

{   //clears intent
    stIntent.clearIntent();
    //sets firstName equal to editFirstName
    stIntent.firstName= editFirstName.getText().toString();
    //sets lastName equal to editLastName
    stIntent.lastName = editLastName.getText().toString();
    //sets streetAddress equal to editStreetAddress
    stIntent.streetAddress =editStreetAddress.getText().toString();
    //sets town equal to editTown
    stIntent.town = editTown.getText().toString();
    //sets state equal to editState
    stIntent.state = editState.getText().toString();
    //sets zip equal to editZip
    stIntent.zip = editZip.getText().toString();
    //sets result passing result and the intent as arguments
    setResult(result, stIntent.getIntent());
    //calls super.finish method
    super.finish();
}
}
```

Comment: You are missing spaces in several occasions while you are building the create statement of the table. Change all `"text not null` to `" text not null`. Then uninstall the app from the device and rerun.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the cause is an issue with SDK 31.

The options to circumvent this is to do one of the following:-

1. Change to use SDK 30 in the build gradle.
2. Use `@SuppressLint("Range")` on the line before `private AddressAttributeGroup cursorToAddressAttributeGroup(Cursor cursor)`
3. Use [`getColumnIndexOrThrow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)) instead of `getColumnIndex`
4. get the index prior to the get????

e.g.

```
int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(AddressDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID);
cursor.getInt(idx);
```

You should also change :

```
// Database creation SQL statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "create table "
        + TABLE_ADDRESS  + "("
        + COLUMN_ID      + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        +COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " text not null, "
        +COLUMN_LASTNAME + "text not null, "
        +COLUMN_STREET_ADDRESS + "text not null, "
        +COLUMN_TOWN + "text not null, "
        +COLUMN_STATE + "text not null, "
        +COLUMN_ZIP + "text not null);";
```

to :-

```
// Database creation SQL statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "create table "
        + TABLE_ADDRESS  + "("
        + COLUMN_ID      + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        +COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " text not null, "
        +COLUMN_LASTNAME + " text not null, "
        +COLUMN_STREET_ADDRESS + "text not null, " //<<<<< ADDED SPACE
        +COLUMN_TOWN + " text not null, " //<<<<< ADDED SPACE
        +COLUMN_STATE + " text not null, " //<<<<< ADDED SPACE
        +COLUMN_ZIP + " text not null);"; //<<<<< ADDED SPACE
```

As otherwise the column names (those commented with `//<<<<< ADDED SPACE`) will be the expected column name suffixed with text and would then result in -1 being returned and a resultant column index error when run. e.g. Instead of **lastname** the column name would be **lastnametext**